# What is the most similar web framework to Web2py (Python) but for PHP?

Tags: php, web-frameworks

Things I love about Web2Py:

- Neatness of template views
- Ease of site setup with basic features like
  signup/login, form validation, and
  AJAX.

I'm switching over to PHP for my own reasons but I'm trying to find a similar web framework to Web2Py.  What is the most similar?

Answer (score 1):

There is no framework in PHP similar to web2py.